# Display Hidden Content on Mouseover - JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

Please help. I'm very new to JQuery.

I adopted a jquery tooltip for a tab navigation i'm working on.

The premise is that when you hover a tab a floating span (tooltip) is displayed. The hover is successful. But the div that contains the content doesn't show and keeps getting stuck on first content div.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabcont div:not(:first)').hide();

    $('#ltabs ul li a').append('<span></span>');
    $('#ltabs ul li a').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('span').animate({opacity:'show', top: '-2'}, 'fast');
            var hoverTexts = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).find('span').text(hoverTexts);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('span').animate({opacity:'hide', top: '-2'}, 'fast');
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

<div id="ltabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tab"><a href="#content1" name="Tab1" class="active"><h1>Tab1</h1></a></li>
                        <li class="tab"><a href="#content2" name="Tab2"><h1>Tab2</h1></a></li>
                        <li class="tab"><a href="#content3" name="Tab3"><h1>Tab3</h1></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tabcont">
                    <div id="content1">
                    <!--LContent1-->
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p>  
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content2">
                    <!--LContent2-->
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p>  
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content3">
                    <!--LContent3-->
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p> 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p> 
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel quam augue, vel rhoncus arcu</p>
                    </div>  
                    </div>      
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a jQuery, but a CSS issue. You have to position your tooltip relatively to its parent - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZLZT/1/)

```css
#ltabs ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#ltabs ul li a span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, Zoltan. I'm actually having problems making the content area change at the moment Would you know a workaround?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tZLZT/2/ or you might want to look into jQuery UI tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check these out and let you know things pan out.